# How to tell when a variable goes out of scope?

Tags: algorithm, garbage-collection, compiler-construction, closures, reference-counting

In doing reference counting, one of the tasks is to "decrement the counter when the variable goes out of scope". But my biggest problem is I can't tell in my head when a variable goes out of scope, at the implementation level of implementing a reference counter.

Could one explain all (or the main) ways in which a variable can go out of scope?

I am specifically talking about in the case of a highly advanced programming language, not a toy / introductory undergraduate language. I am thinking like with JavaScript or Rust, which has closures and nested function definitions (at least in the case of JavaScript). Also when you are using pointers and such and using mutable function parameters. Say you pass in a mutable value to a function, then return a closure using that mutable value, stuff like that.

What are all the ways you can tell when a variable goes out of scope? How do I get this organized enough so I can add it to a reference counter?

Answer (score 1):

A local variable goes out of scope when execution reaches the end of the block in which it was declared.

Variables that are global / static don't ever go out of scope.

Variables that are fields of a composite data type (an class / object, a struct / record, an array, etc) may not have a "scope" per se, but if they do, it is determined by the scope of the composite data type instance they are part of.

If you are trying to analyses this at compile time ... you use a symbol table.  This is covered in textbooks on compiler writing.

Comment: But what about closures, is it really that easy? "A local variable goes out of scope when execution reaches the end of the block in which it was declared."

Comment: OK ... so you need to be more clear about what you mean by scope.  Do you mean dynamic scope or lexical scope?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope

Comment: Basically, if a language supports dynamic scopes, the compiler cannot determine when a dynamic scope exits.  It needs to be handled at runtime; e.g. by the garbage collector or using reference counts or something.